# This drip is causing my 2000 HONDA CRV to overheat

Tags: leak

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JaDZ_2jp3lQ

Can someone please help me identify where this drip is coming from?
It empties both the antifreeze and radiator.
Ty

Answer (score 3):

Since it appears to be coming from above the crank shaft, I would look at the waterpump. It could be a hose or loose clamp. The likely cause the water pump. Most have a small hole that leak when the pump seals fail. Although you don't specify which engine, you may want to consider changing the timing belt also. Most Hondas drive the water pump with the timing belt. With all labor involved with doing just the pump I do the belt while it is apart.